# Regarding the binary "bit position" nomenclature

Tags: c, binary, bit

So while reading the K&R "The C Programming Language" I came across this exercise:

***Question***: Write a function setbits(x,p,n,y) that returns x with the n bits that begin at position p set to the rightmost n bits of y, leaving the other bits unchanged.

What I don't understand is how to count the bit position, should I start from 1 or 0?

**For example with the exercise in mind it would be:**
 With `n = 3, p = 4, X= 00100000 //32, Y= 00001011 //11`:

```
             p
             n n n
  X= 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 // Number 32
pos: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

  Y= 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 // Number 11
               n n n
```

That will result to:

```
        p
        n n n
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 // Number 38
```

***Or it could be:***

```
           p
           n n n
  X= 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 // Number 32
pos: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

  Y= 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 // Number 11
               n n n
```

That will result to:

```
      p
      n n n
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 // Number 44
```

**So my question is: What is the most common way of counting the bit position? Should you start from 0 or from 1?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't understand is how to count the bit position, should I start from 1 or 0?

The bit count always starts at 0

Example:

```
unsigned int x = 8;
unsigned int y = x >> 0; // Here you are saying shift x by 0 bit times 

printf("%d: \n", y);
y = x >> 1; // Here you are saying shift x by 1 bit position to left...
printf("%d: \n", y);
```

and you know shifting left 1 time means divide by 2. If you are shifting left 0 times means divided by 1 (2 power 0)
Hope this message was conveyed to you properly.

Comment: The `>>` operator really doesn't shift left. :)